# Why do I get the wrong address when referencing a global variable?

Tags: c++, memory, operating-system

I am trying to write a basic OS to better understand OS fundamentals and I am running into a strange problem. After switching to protected mode I jump into my kernel.  In my kernel.cpp file I declare the following global variables (where IdtPointer_t and IdtEntry_t are both structs.)

```
IdtPointer_t idtPtr;
IdtEntry_t idtEntries[256];
```

This creates the idtPtr and idtEntries variables in the bss section.
Then later in my code when I do the following

```
IdtEntry_t* entry = &idtEntries[0];
```

the value returned by &idtEntries[0] isn't the correct address.  Using GDB I have done the following

```
p &idtEntries[0]
(IdtEntry_t *) 0x87a0 <idtEntries>
p entry
(IdtEntry_t *) 0x87e0 <idtEntries+64>
```

There is a 64 byte difference between the locations of the two variables.  Why does referencing the variable return a different address than where the variable is stored in memory?

Also, I am running this using the qemu i386 emulator.

Comment: What happens if you change the order of declarations of `idtPtr` and `idtEntries`?

Comment: Are you changing `entry` between when you initialize it and when you look at it in gdb?  A [mcve] would help.

Comment: Could gdb be reporting this incorrectly - perhaps because you are compile optimised?

Comment: Are these lines in the same compilation unit?

Comment: What do you get if you print these variables in code?

Answer (score 0):

Why does referencing the variable return a different address than where the variable is stored in memory? It does not. I strongly suspect that what GDB is displaying is not what you think it is displaying (although I'm no GDB expert).

Assuming you are developing this on a linux system, I suggest supplementing your observations with the output of 'nm' (or it's cross-compiler relative).

```
nm -n <elf file>
```

This will reliably give you a list of all the symbols in your kernel/OS and their addresses (sorted by numerical order). Then compare the addresses of 'idtEntries' and 'entry' against what you got in GDB.